# Scroll to beginning of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small problem. To scroll child in the begging of parent. After 
 click button 'BOOK NOW' this block must be scroll at the begging of popup[image]

I try something like this

```
jQuery('.booking-now').each(function(){

jQuery(this).click(function(e){

    var btn = jQuery(this);
    var btnParent = btn.closest('.sidebar-wrapper');
    var btnParentOffset = 0;
    function getParentOffset() {
        return btnParentOffset = btnParent.offset().top
    }
    getParentOffset();

    console.log(btnParentOffset);

    jQuery('.events-booking-custom').animate({
                      scrollTop: btnParentOffset
                  }, 500);
    })
})
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Highdef I edit my question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, it looks like you are trying to scroll the `.events-booking-custom` instead of the HTML/body:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: buttonParentOffset
}, 500);
```

Secondly, it doesn't look like you are preventing the default action for the button:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong though. Do you have a sample of the HTML or can you create a JSFiddle?